# Find scale factors to maximize images size

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, programming

I have two images with dimensions $w_1 \times h_1$ and $w_2 \times h_2$ respectively. I want to display them in a screen of size $w_{screen} \times h_{screen}$. My goal is to resize those images with respect to their aspect ratio such that their sizes are maximized in the screen.

The images will be placed next to each other in the screen, and their layout depends on the screen orientation (as a top-bottom in portrait, or as a side-by-side in landscape).

The images can have different aspect ratio, meaning that they are not just squares. They can have any kind of size (with $w_1, h_1, w_2, h_2 \gt 0$).

Hence, I'm looking for two scale factors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are associated to the first and second image respectively.

To compute the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I use the following linear programming model:

We consider $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be the variables to optimize:

$$
\max_{\alpha, \beta} \quad z = \alpha \cdot w_1 \cdot h_1 + \beta \cdot w_2 \cdot h_2
$$

subject to:

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha \cdot w_1 &\le w_{screen} \tag{1}\label{eq1}\\
\alpha \cdot h_1 &\le h_{screen} \tag{2}\label{eq2}\\
\beta \cdot w_2 &\le w_{screen} \tag{3}\label{eq3}\\
\beta \cdot h_2 &\le h_{screen \tag{4}\label{eq4}}\\
\alpha, \beta &\ge 0 \tag{5}\label{eq5}\\
\end{align}
$$

(In the optimization function $z$, I use the image area as a unit to measure how big they are).

Although I can use the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) to resolve the problem, my final goal is to use this method in a computer program to realize a responsive user interface, and thus I would like to find a simpler formula to compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: So you want to values, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which will be used to scale 2 images? It's not clear, are the two images going to be displayed at the same time on the screen? If so,  in what orientation? Are they going to be side by side or top and bottom? Or are you looking for something that will determine the best orientation as well as the best scaling factors?

Comment: I changed the subject to clarify this: The layout depends on the screen orientation. If it is a portrait, the images are placed top-bottom, and if it is a landscape, they are placed left-right.

The goal is not to change the orientation, just the scale factors.

Comment: Suppose $w_1:h_1$ is equal to the screen's aspect ratio and $w_2:h_2$ is not. Then you maximize $z$ by setting $\alpha$ so $w_1$ equals the width of the screen and setting $\beta=0$. Surely this is not a desirable solution.

Comment: David's point is exactly my thought. If you are just trying to optimize for area you'll likely get one image just cut out completely. What do you think about splitting the screen into 2 areas (left and right or top and bottom) and trying to maximize image 1 in area 1 and image 2 in area 2? This might give a more desirable result.

Comment: I agree, David's comment makes me realize that my model is ill-formed. I don't have a workaround for this, so I will settle with Caedmon's solution for now.